# How can I hide the TotalTerminal Visor from the command line?

Tags: terminal

I am using TotalTerminal. I know that I can set hotkeys to show or hide TotalTerminal's visor, but is there a command I can put at the end of a command line to hide it?

For example:

```
latex ; hide-total-terminal-window
```

Is there a command that can implement the same function as this hotkey setting? For example, the hotkey to hide TotalTerminal is ⌃T, so I want to find the corresponding command line option that will hide TotalTerminal instead of having to press the hotkey.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are you asking. Do you need a hot-key that hides only (i.e. a no-op if already hidden) instead of toggling between hide and show?

Comment: I know I can use hotkey to hide visor. What I want to do is: I want to compile latex from terminal(there is a reason I want to do this rather than use texshop), so I type "latex ...." command in terminal, but I have to press the hotkey to hide visor every time. So I want to know is there a command to hide visor so I just need to add this command after the "latex" command with ";". Thanks.

Comment: I edited your question, as you should have done, few people will read through all the comments to see if there is a clarification. If total-terminal was an X application you could use a script that called `wmctrl` but I don't think it is.

Comment: thanks. I have posted new questions after the original question.